# .bashrc not activating conda

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda

I have conda `4.5.11` and I am trying to run a bash script whereby I activate the coda environment I created. However it keeps telling me:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the current user with

    $ echo ". /nvme/h/buildsets/eb_cyclone/software/Anaconda3/5.3.0/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc

or, for all users, enable conda with

    $ sudo ln -s /nvme/h/buildsets/eb_cyclone/software/Anaconda3/5.3.0/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh

The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but they do NOT
put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so, run

    $ conda activate

in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently, run

    $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc

Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to modify PATH in
your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the line that looks like

    export PATH="/nvme/h/buildsets/eb_cyclone/software/Anaconda3/5.3.0/bin:$PATH"

^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_foml_trans.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

However this is how my `.bashrc` looks like:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
export DATA_p077=/onyx/data/p077
export DATA_p078=/onyx/data/p078
. /nvme/h/buildsets/eb_cyclone/software/Anaconda3/5.3.0/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate
```

I am not sure what is happening and how to resolve this error although it is obvious from the message, but everything is there its a weird behavior.

This is the bash script I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --job-name=fgpu
#SBATCH --account=p077
#SBATCH --partition=gpu
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --gpus=1
#SBATCH --mem=16000
#SBATCH --time=0-01:00:00

module load Anaconda3/5.3.0   
conda activate tensorflow-dementia

jobid=$SLURM_JOBID

python main_foml_trans.py > job${jobid}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The SLURM script won't source `.bashrc` unless the shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env bash -l`. Also, I wouldn't include the `conda activate` in the `.bashrc`, unless you definitely want the **base** environment activated by default - it is not necessary.

BTW, if you use a newer Conda, then you could just use:

```bash
conda run -n tensorflow-dementia python main_foml_trans.py > job${jobid}.txt
```

No activation necessary. In general, you'd probably have a better experience not using your system-level Anaconda, and just installing Mambaforge for yourself.